# Horizontal long text like newspaper

Tags: css

Lets say I've got long lorem ipsum in div. Div width is 30% and there is so much text that page need to scroll up/down. I want to make it scrolling horizontally: when there is more text than can fit in div I want it to continue in next column next to the first one, equally like in almost every newspaper etc.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

[**Use CSS3 multi-column layouts**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_multi-column_layouts)

Check [Demo Page here](http://www.csscripting.com/css-multi-column/example1.php)

You can now use any of these CSS3 multi-column properties in your stylesheet:

```
column-count: 3;
column-width: 300px;
column-gap:10px;
column-rule: 1px solid #999;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use : `overflow-x: scroll`